# Is there any method like code first in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I am searching for a way for creating database by my models structure in Laravel 5.5.

I know many Orm Like Doctorin Or ActiveRecord has this feature and so some micro Orm such as redbean has this feature but I cannot find a good reference for this ability in *eloquent* ORM of Laravel and if there is any method has it migrations which alter my existing database according to my model changes?

Comment: Laravel doesn't have Model First code built in but there may be a third party package.   I'm not sure how it would work since you can't really define a specific type or length of a field in a model.  It's usually pretty easy to add to, or create a new, migration when you change or add a field though.

Comment: The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. It is from the documentation. Maybe,  I do not understand, but what is your problem?

Comment: my problem is code first or model first built in laravel